# Set BadgeValue for ToolbarItems.UIBarButtonItem in MonoTouch

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uibarbuttonitem, uitabbaritem, badge

I'm pretty new to MonoTouch development, but I've been using the handy `ToolbarItems` property on the `UIViewController` to show some toolbar buttons and now I'm looking for a way to set the `BadgeValue` on some of those buttons.

It seems that the `UIBarButtonItem` class is missing the `BadgeValue` property you see on `UITabBarItem`, so the question is - how to set the badge value for a `UIBarButtonItem` in the `ToolbarItems` collection ?

```
UIBarButtonItem item1 = new UIBarButtonItem() { Title = "test" };
//item1.BadgeValue = "3"; //this doesn't work
ToolbarItems = new UIBarButtonItem[] { item1 };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both [`UIBarButtonItem`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [UITabBarItem](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html) inherit from `UIBarItem`. Sadly `BadgeValue` is only available for [UITabBarItem](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIBarItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIBarItem) so you'll need to **reimplement** this feature yourself.

This question (and answer) should help you: [How to add Badges on UIBarbutton item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5684636/how-to-add-badges-on-uibarbutton-item)

But be warned that it might now look as good as a real badge.

Comment: Awww, so sad, I was afraid I was going to get that answer :/ I guess I have to use a view controller inside tab bar controller then.