# how to display Notification Count in iOS like Facebook

Tags: ios, facebook

I want to display Notification Count in iOS like Facebook as per attachment.! [image]

I have found https://github.com/JaviSoto/JSBadgeView but it's just for Launcher icon.

Comment: I found that answer is correct.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5684636/how-to-add-badges-on-uibarbutton-item

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an image that contains the badge and set it on the `UIBarButtonItem`. You can probably create a function that generates a badge and puts it on an image using `Core Graphics`