# Add ImageView and Label as UIBarButton for UINavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I'm trying to display a number and an image as a bar button Item, but I don't know how to implement that.
I'm adding a shopping cart button in my `UINavigationController`, which displays a shopping cart icon as an image, and the number of products inside the cart.

How can I make a similar button?

For example this is what the Amazon App has got:
[image]

Comment: Make a UIbutton, set its backgroundimage or just image. Place a tiny label at the position where you want to show the number of products. Set value of products as you want & perform your action by clicking the button. Remember, Button should be below the label in hierarchy or it will interfere with touch events.

Comment: Alternatively you can set background image of button and set button title to number of products, if that works for you. For me personally it always mucks up the UI so I go with first approach

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5684636/how-to-add-badges-on-uibarbutton-item (i prefer second answer in this link)

Comment: @NSNoob Thanks, I added the CustomButtron as leftBarButtonItem .But I notice that It destroys the backbarbutton .Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Hope This Helps..this code only for right side image

```
viewController.navigationItem.titleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimage.png"]];
UIBarButtonItem * item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimage2.jpg"]]];    
viewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = item;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer [Badge Barbutton](https://github.com/mikeMTOL/UIBarButtonItem-Badge).By using this, can customise badgeBGColor,badgeTextColor, badgeFont, badgePadding, badgeMinSize, shouldHideBadgeAtZero and shouldAnimateBadge. Perfect for cart kind of bar icons.

Comment: Does it have Swift version?

Comment: i don't think so. You can bridge it.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer following link
https://github.com/TanguyAladenise/BBBadgeBarButtonItem/blob/master/Example/BBBadgeBarButtonItem/BBViewController.m
It might help.