# How to add a TabBar badge?

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller

I tries this code but the badge is not showing up

```
tabBarController?.tabBar.Item![3].badgeValue = "3"
```

I added this code to my TabBarController class
Is this the right way to add it?

Comment: Check out  [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5684636/how-to-add-badges-on-uibarbutton-item#).

Comment: If it's in a subclass of `UITabBarController`, it should be `self.tabBar.Item![3].badgeValue ="3"`

Comment: @beyowulf Please add it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be like this : `self.tabBar.Item![3].badgeValue ="3"` because it seems to be a subclass.